# Code not looping through the rest of my file or resetting the counter

Tags: python, string, csv, if-statement, counter

Currently trying to loop through a file with addresses in python, but for some reason instead of looping through the entire file - it stops at the first line.

I tried resetting the counter and making it go back to the first if statement but it still only spits out the first address and continues printing the other lines.

If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it!

My code:

```
starter_file = 'addresses.csv'
output_file = 'new_address.csv'
new_address = ''
line_counter = 0

def save_file(filename, file_mode, content):
    with open (filename, mode=file_mode, encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        output_file.write(content)

with open(starter_file, mode='r') as map_data:
    for each_line in map_data.readlines():

        if line_counter == 0:
            header = 'street, city, state, zip, coordinates\n'
            save_file(output_file, 'a+', header)
            
        if line_counter == 1:   # street 
            new_address = each_line[1:].strip()     # remove initial ", strip \n from enconding

        if line_counter == 2:   # city, st, zip
            city_state_zip = each_line.strip()
            city_end = len(each_line) - 8
            city = city_state_zip[:city_end]

            state = city_state_zip[city_end:city_end+2]

            zip_code = city_state_zip[-5:]
            
            new_address = new_address + ', ' + city + state + ', ' + zip_code

        if line_counter == 3:   # coordinates
            new_address = new_address + ', ' + each_line.replace(',', ';')
            save_file(output_file, 'a+', new_address)

        if line_counter > 3:
            line_counter == 1

            
        print('#' + str(line_counter) + ' >> ', new_address)

        line_counter += 1
```

Output:

```
#0 >>  
#1 >>  330 Utica Avenue
#2 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213
#3 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"

#4 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"

#5 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"

#6 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"

#7 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"

#8 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"

#9 >>  330 Utica Avenue, Brooklyn, NY , 11213, (40.66668313300005; -73.93135881299997)"
```

And then it continues looping.

Comment: Your code ignores `each_line` after `line_counter` becomes greater than `3`. Did you mean to write: `if line_counter > 3: line_counter = 1`?

Comment: And after you fix that, notice that it will never do the `# street` condition again. After you set it back to 1, `line_counter += 1` will increment it to 2. So from then on you'll only do `city, st, zip` and `coordinates` for the rest of the file. Is that intentional? I suspect you actually want `line_counter = 0` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the following part of your code?

```py
if line_counter > 3:
    line_counter == 1

# ...

line_counter += 1
```

When `line_counter > 3`, it essentially is set to `2` by the start of the next iteration.

<s>Instead, you can remove the `if` statement altogether and change the last line of your loop to `line_counter = (line_counter + 1) % 3`. If you're unfamiliar with the [modulo operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-a-modulo-operator-in-python/) (`%`), it calculates the remainder. In this case, it creates a "wraparound" effect so that once `line_counter` reaches 3, it is "reset" to 0.</s>

Edit: Actually, as per Barmar's comment, I realize now that `line_counter` is only supposed to be zero once - so the code above wouldn't be very helpful as-is. I would suggest using this instead:

```py
line_counter = (line_counter % 3) + 1
```

This way, once `line_counter == 3`, it wraps around to 1 instead of 0.